# MDX error "Subselects only support the COLUMNS axis"

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I have Chain dimension and I am just testing the MDX code if it works or not. But I am getting error "Subselects only support the COLUMNS axis". If someone please help me?

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].Forecast_Gross_Sales
 AS (

SELECT NON EMPTY [Chain].[Chain Name] ON COLUMNS FROM [Chain]), 

VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Forecast' ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Data Types'  ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATE MEMBER` does not use a `SELECT` statement, but normally a tuple expression. MDX is not SQL.